# How to prevent ngAfterViewInit() to get called before ngOninit completes execution

Tags: angular7

I have used  angular materials for sorting a a table in angular 7 . So what is happening I am calling  rest service from `ngOnInit()` method . Then in ngAfterViewInit I have am wrting the below code for sorting.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {  
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

But what is happening is it is not waiting for the rest service to complete the execution and `ngAfterViewInit` is called before `ngOnInit` completes exceution.

For the above reason Sorting is not happening in Webpage where I am displaying the table.

Answer (score 1):

Saroj, you can use **setTimeOut** for this. In your case if you provide more details we can do this in a different way.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Rest(GET) Service returns a custom java bean array(Student[]) on which sorting is not working[If I use static array data  it is working]

Comment: Altough I have increased the the timeout from 500 to 50000 Sorting is not happening .

Comment: Still ngAfterViewInit  is getting called before ngOnInit

Comment: I think it is taking too much time to get the response from your Backend. So try to sort data in the subscription after getting the data.

Comment: no buddy I am trying to print the response after calling rest services I am seeing the response but still ngAfterViewinit is getting invoked  before ngOnInit

Comment: @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;                                                                              ngAfterViewInit() {
    
      console.log('ngAfterViewInit called') 
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }, 4500000);
      console.log(this.dataSource.data)
    }                                                                                                                    
 We can not do that because MatSort is associated with View